# My 2014 dodge journey is leaking coolant in cabin

Tags: dodge, coolant-leak, journey

My 2014 dodge journey is leaking coolant on the driver side floor board and not sure if it's the heater core or what exactly it is

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If you are leaking coolant into the cabin, the only place for it to come from is from the heater core. It is probably following the path of least resistance and flowing out to the driver's side of the HVAC box.

On a separate note, are you sure it is coolant, or is it just liquid? If it is just liquid (no coolant smell, feels/looks like water), it could be condensation from the A/C evaporator core (in the same general area as the heater core). If the heater core is leaking, you would most likely smell it before you'd feel it on your feet, plus the vehicle would most likely be overheating due to a lack of pressure in the system and loss of coolant.

Usually the condensation collects in the bottom of the HVAC box which has a drain hole in it, and flows out through a drain tube which goes through the body of the vehicle and out onto the ground. If this drain becomes plugged, the condensation will build up and then find it's way out onto your shoes.